# Differences: A* a=new A(); vs. A b; A *c=&b;

Tags: c++, pointers

Asked during interview.

1. `A* a=new A();`
2. `A b; A *c=&b;`

What is the difference between 1 and 2?

I said in 2nd statement, object is created on stack and on heap in 1st. My friend said objects are always created on heap.

What is the right answer?

Comment: Did you get the job? That might be a clue ;-)

Comment: The scopes are not the same too

Comment: *1.* does memoryleak, whereas *2.* doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're kind of right - the second block of code - ***assuming it appears inside a function*** - will have `b` and `c` on the stack, though of course depending on the type of `A` it may have internal pointers to heap-allocated memory (`std::string`, `std::vector` etc. are examples of this, if they're not empty and larger than any internal buffer).

That said, `a` itself would be on the stack in the first block too - it's only the object to which its pointed - `*a`, that's necessarily on the heap.

Put another way, `a` and `c` are effectively equivalent: stack based values, but the former is pointed at a heap-allocated `A` and the second at another stack-allocated `A`....

Answer (score 6):

"Stack" and "heap" are implementation terms. Choice #1 allocates an `A` dynamically, choice #2 does the same thing automatically. Probably the program will end up using something like a heap<sup>*</sup> for dynamic storage and a stack for automatic, but that's not guaranteed.

But accepting the loose usage of the term, it is certainly not correct that "objects are always created on the heap." Maybe your friend is thinking of Java?

<sup>*</sup>not in the data structures sense of the word

Comment: Why not guaranteed? C++ is low level enough to be unable to change this behavior.

Comment: @Sarge The standard specifies when storage space should be allocated and freed (among other things), but it doesn't dictate what types of data structures should be used to manage it. That's up to whomever writes the compiler. The rules of automatic allocation mean a stack is a natural fit, but if the author of some compiler felt it was easier just to put everything in one big heap (and add a lot of overhead to automatic (de)allocations), that would be allowed.